# OneSignal clear all notifications Native Android

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I created an android app in which I use **OneSignal** to send Notifications from **PHP-API**. These Notifications are about order details. I want that when the user opens OrdersActivity in-app, all the notifications **automatically removed**. I know it is possible, but I am new at using OneSignal.

I only use this code in the app to subscribe device:

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();
```

Comment: Have you tried using **OneSignal.clearOneSignalNotifications()** when you open your activity from notification click?

Comment: Also I want to open OrdersActivity by clicking on Notification, can you help me?

Comment: You can create custom **NotificationOpenHandler** class which extends **OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler** and in there you can override a method named **notificationOpened** and in it you can handle you notification accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `OneSignal.clearOneSignalNotifications()` when you open your activity from notification click it'll solve your issue.